# Faster way to read a keyword list

Tags: c, parsing, lexer, jump-table

I'm writing a simple lexer for a general purpose programming language and one of the token types is a 'keyword' that has some predefined control flow tokens such as 'if', 'else', 'while', 'return'.

I want to know the fastest way to check if some keyword is inside my list using x86 Standard C.

My idea was to use a jump table but C string comparisons is problematic since C strings are arrays of char type.

Comment: create an enum?

Comment: @h0m3 There is no such this as "x86 Standard C (gcc)". There is  standard C and GCC which allows you to write code using standard C for x86 architectures. And to answer your question, the easiest way is to keep a sorted static array of keywords and do a binary search. For trivial things such as this, that's the easiest and fastest way.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer Yes. That is what i meant. (x86) (Standard C) (gcc).

Because even using Standards the compiler and architecture can influenciate on performance.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to hand-build a trie, or equivalently a state machine. Flex (or any other lex variant) would do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically a hash table provides lookup of O(1). However, I would implement a static look up table. Assuming the number of tokens you are searching for is small. A linear search of the table shouldn’t prove too costly.